# Render a region in a panel

Tags: panels, theming

What I want to do is to render a region in a panel -> add content -> new custom content.
I tried `<?php print render($page['region_name']); ?>` but it didn't work.

I'm using panels to be able to create more complex layouts and the Context module to show blocks (with menus) on different pages. Thats why I need to render a region in a panel: to put menus on selected pages.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, as what you are trying to do makes no sense to me. I've never tried to use both context and panels at the same time, but it seems like a good way to cause issues headaches.

Answer (score 2):

This code is not to supposed to work inside panels. Regions are what you add to your themes and they are ready to use on your theme templates.Panels are used to override your theme templates, its allows to have regions as per the panel layout you choose.$page will not be available to your panels. Using new custom content you can add plain text,html,php but regions will be available here.